# Identify 12-piece wooden puzzle with two colors

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

I bought this puzzle (without box, dismantled, no idea how it was before) and I can’t figure out how it should look like. There are 12 wood pieces (6 black / 6 white) which are roughly 5 x 1 x 1. They are 3 sets of 4 identical pieces (2 black and 2 white for each kind) One set is the twin of the other (only reversed). What should this puzzle look like?

[image]

Comment: Search "burr puzzle" in your browser. Those 12 pieces make either 2 regular-sized (6 pieces) or 1 double-size (12 pieces).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried to look for 12 pieces Burr puzzle and 6 pieces, but I can’t find any with pieces similar to mine. 

Maybe there is some missing pieces pieces…

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two six-piece burrs. There's a good introduction by [Stewart Coffin](https://johnrausch.com/PuzzlingWorld/chap05.htm), and the classic analysis of all possible combinations for this puzzle was done by [Bill Cutler](https://billcutlerpuzzles.com/docs/CA6PB/index.html).

I would guess that the dark six make one puzzle and the light six make another, although it's possible you might be able to do some mixing and matching to make valid combinations.

I built a full set of 42 pieces that can be combined to make 221 combinations. It's a fun project.

When I look at the notches on your pieces, though, the two at the bottom of the photo don't match any in the standard set. As JLee suggested in the comments, you might have a [twelve-piece burr](https://www.instructables.com/Burr-Puzzle/).

Comment: They don't look like six-piece burr pieces. Some of them have two slots separated by a central bar.

Comment: @fljx good point. Looks like a 12 pc burr puzzle

Answer (score 1):

I have this puzzle too!  I think I got it at a yard sale years ago.  It goes together nicely.

[image]